# Use CloudKit to return users records and deny accounts

Tags: swift, cloudkit

instead of code, have more of a best practice/functionality question regarding CloudKit.  Can't seem to find answers, or maybe just don't understand.

Questions:

1. When I save the record, cloud kit creates a unique record id, i was thinking of getting that id and storing in core data to allow specific query's on that at a later time vs entire database searches.  However, once I save a record, how do i get the record id that was created?  Is this possible?
2. What if I allow a user to report another user for some reason and thereby want to block that user from posting to the cloud until a review can be done. Is there a user access database in the cloud?  if not, thoughts on how to?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you create a CKRecord it will generate a guid as it's ID. You can also specify your own id the moment you create the CKRecord. The it does not need to be a guid. As long as it's unique. Your save action will have a callback where you will get the ID.

Every user has it's own unique id which you can easily get. You could create a table with your blocking information. You only have to query for that yourself to implement the blocking mechanism.

Comment: thank you, makes sense.  How would you implement a call back?  Is that a Notification?

Comment: I meant the completionHandler of the save action. The record will contain the ID. See : database.saveRecord(theRecord, completionHandler: { record, error in